# How to Install github magento extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-community

Bit of a daft question, but I need some advice.
I have found an extension on github and downloaded it to my PC.
When it comes to uploading it to my server via FTP, I know I should copy across the ‘app’ folder but there are also files called ‘composer.json’ and the ‘LICENSE’ file.
Do I also have to upload them too?
Thanks for any help.
Sam.

Comment: no need to upload those files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally all files with these extensions on the root path folder don't need to upload.

### Extensions

.md

.json

.txt

.html

.ini

.sample

LICENSE

README